# Include QtMultimedia (or whatever is needed for QSound) module using CMake

Tags: qt, cmake

My question probably boils down to "what is the module called".

I'd like to use the **QSound** class in Qt 5.4 and apparently
the "Qt5Multimedia" module is not pulled in alongside QtGui and
QtCore when calling

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
```

So I browse my Qt 5.4 installation (locally on Debian) and in fact find a directory

```
~/sw/Qt/Qt_5_4/5.4/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Multimedia
```

However, naively adding

```
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)
```

to my **CMakeLists.txt** fails with this paraphrasis of *"File not found error."*:

```
By not providing "FindQt5Multimedia.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"Qt5Multimedia", but CMake did not find one.
```

So, within said directory, I ask **ls -1** and actually get more than I wanted:

```
Qt5Multimedia_CameraBinServicePlugin.cmake
Qt5MultimediaConfig.cmake
Qt5MultimediaConfigVersion.cmake
Qt5Multimedia_QAlsaPlugin.cmake
Qt5Multimedia_QGstreamerAudioDecoderServicePlugin.cmake
Qt5Multimedia_QGstreamerCaptureServicePlugin.cmake
Qt5Multimedia_QGstreamerPlayerServicePlugin.cmake
Qt5Multimedia_QM3uPlaylistPlugin.cmake
Qt5Multimedia_QPulseAudioPlugin.cmake
```

Could any of you tell me, which to take, if any, in order to being
able to use the QSound class to play some .wav files?

Comment: You might need to add `~/sw/Qt/Qt_5_4/5.4/gcc_64/` to the environment variable `$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to let CMake know where the Qt5 specific files are located.

Comment: I was not thinking about that because I already have such a line within my CMakeLists.txt. But as it turns out it _was_ personalized on QtWidgets. I now updated it to

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  "/home/kochmn/sw/Qt/Qt_5_4/5.4/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets;/home/kochmn/sw/Qt/Qt_5_4/5.4/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Multimedia"
)

which actually seems to fix the issue. Thank you for the hint! :-)

Comment: On a second try, seeing you propose a shorter path, I simply used set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/kochmn/sw/Qt/Qt_5_4/5.4/gcc_64/lib/cmake/") which seems to work as well for both modules at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting my comment into this answer to close this question:

CMake needs to know where the Qt5 specific files are located.
Therefore you should add `~/sw/Qt/Qt_5_4/5.4/gcc_64/` either to the environment variable `$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or set it using

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/sw/Qt/Qt_5_4/5.4/gcc_64/")
```

Then CMake will be able to perform `find_package(Qt5Multimedia)`.

Comment: Jep. This is the orderly thing to do. Thanks again! And now I can even accept your answer! ;-)

Comment: if you set QTDIR cmake should be able to locate Qt in find_package as well, with the added bonus of not hardcoding paths in your CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 5):

For me worked after installing `qtmultimedia5-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev
```